# selenium c# to find if one out of two elements is present

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i am writing a test to find element A or element B. I am writing these lines, not sure how do i structure it, as i want to use OR

```
Assert.IsTrue((WebDriver.FindElement(ByXpath("elementA")))||(WebDriver.FindElement(ByXpath("elementB"))));
```

I am also thinking of using if...elseif, but there is no action, I just want the test presence of one or other.

```
if (IsElementPresent(ByXpath("elementA")))
            {
                //what to do here?
            }
            else if (IsElementPresent(ByXpath("elementB")))
            {
                //????
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this also...

```
bool ele = Driver.IsElementPresent(By.Xpath("path"));
bool ele2 = Driver.IsElementPresent(By.Xpath("path"));
```

Then you could assert this way as an or operator

```
Assert.IsTrue(ele | ele2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add it in a try catch

```
try
{
assert.IsTrue(<YourElementA>);
}
catch(Exception)
{
assert.IsTrue(<YourElementb>);
}
```